# Is it possible to determine the probabilities with this information?

Tags: probability, expected-value

I play a game where there are loot boxes that follow a probability distribution. In a loot box, you always have 3 loot pieces.

The following information is given:

Chance of ATLEAST 1:

1. 100% - Rare Item or Better
2. 24.8% - Epic or Better
3. 7.4% - Legendary

Every loot box contains at least one "Rare" item or better. The other two items can also be rare, epic, or legendary. But can also be common.

I would like to know the probabilities of each without the "or better" part. As Epic or better means legendary. So for Epic or Legendary, you have a 24.8% chance. Which (If I'm right) gives Epic a chance of 24.8-7.4 = 17.4%

The tricky part is in the common items, which is not given. I thought of calculating it as follows: Common item chance = 1-rare-epic-legendary

In the end, I would like to calculate the expected value of one pack. Can that be done with the given information?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure it can be done. But I don't have enough knowledge in probability

Comment: Or better also could mean multiple of that card not necessarily the next best card

Comment: No, it can't be done with the information given. For instance, it may be that all three items always have the same level of legendariness. In this case, you never get a common item.

Comment: You do not know, for example, what is the chance of finding legendary items, but not epic ones, so it cannot be done. You can only find bounds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it cannot be done. For ease of presentation I'll change the probabilities to rounder numbers, but the point remains regardless of actual values of the numbers.

Consider the following 4 boxes:

(R,R,R)
(R,R,E)
(R,R,E)
(R,R,L)

compared to the other 4 boxes

(R,R,R)
(R,E,E)
(R,E,E)
(R,E,L)

in both cases, the probability of getting at least 1 E or better is 75%, and the probability of getting at least 1 L is 25%. But in the first, the probability getting at least 1 E is 50%, while in the second it is 75%.